# SQL Server 2017 Merge Not Running Triggers

Tags: trigger, sql-server-2017, merge

Everywhere I am reading, when a merge statement happens, it will fire the triggers (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) in no particular order.  I have a basic merge:

```
MERGE dbo.Users WITH(HOLDLOCK) as tgt
USING #Users as src
ON tgt.ID = src.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY INSERT
(..)
VALUES(..)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, src.UserID into #Results;
```

However, I have an insert trigger on Users but nothing ever gets run from the trigger perspective.  Follow-up update statements do get run and I see the results of those trigger executions, just not the inserts from the merge.

Is there anything I can do about that?  I'm surprised it's not working when it's documented that others do get that functionality to work...

Comment: Hi, could you add a reproducable example? When testing with my own merge statement + trigger it does work. Using [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) can help in supplying an example that clarifies your question.

Comment: Is the trigger smart enough to handle multiple rows being inserted? Does it work if you limit the merge to insert a single row?